# Using textFieldShouldReturn method to move the focus to next textField it is not working in Apple TV App

Tags: swift, tvos

Connection made to UITextFieldDelegate. So no issue related to delegate connection. Below is my code.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if (textField == self.userNameTxt) {
        self.passwordTxt.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

If anybody knows the answer please let me know. Thanks

Comment: So every time the else is executed?

Comment: @Rakesha No it goes into if part but focus doesn't move to passwordTxt Field.

Comment: Check if `passwordTxt` is actually on your screen then.

Comment: @Rakesha yes it is on the screen and next to the userNameTxt Field. This code works well on iOS app. but on Apple TV, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

With tvOS you have to set the logic inside the function textFieldDidEndEditing :

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        firstTextField.delegate = self
        secondTextField.delegate = self
        firstTextField.tag = 0
        secondTextField.tag = 1
    }
}
extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if (textField.tag == 0){
            secondTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```